# How to bind Slick dependency with Lagom?

Tags: scala, slick, lagom

So, I have this dependency which is used to create tables and interact with `Postgres`. Here is a Sample Class:

```
class ConfigTable {

  this: DBFactory =>

  import driver.api._

  implicit val configKeyMapper = MappedColumnType.base[ConfigKey, String](e => e.toString, s => ConfigKey.withName(s))

  val configs = TableQuery[ConfigMapping]

  class ConfigMapping(tag: Tag) extends Table[Config](tag, "configs") {

    def key = column[ConfigKey]("key")
    def value = column[String]("value")
    def * = (key, value) <> (Config.tupled, Config.unapply _)
  }

  /**
    * add config
    *
    * @param config
    * @return
    */
  def add(config: Config): Try[Config] = try {
    sync(db.run(configs += config)) match {
      case 1 => Success(config)
      case _ => Failure(new Exception("Unable to add config"))
    }
  } catch {
    case ex: PSQLException =>
      if (ex.getMessage.contains("duplicate key value")) Failure(new Exception("alt id already exists."))
      else Failure(new Exception(ex.getMessage))
  }

  def get(key: ConfigKey): Option[Config] = sync(db.run(configs.filter(x => x.key === key).result)).headOption

  def getAll(): Seq[Config] = sync(db.run(configs.result))

}

object ConfigTable extends ConfigTable with PSQLComponent
```

PSQLComponent is the Abstraction for Database meta configuration:

import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile

```
trait PSQLComponent extends DBFactory {

  val driver = PostgresProfile

  import driver.api.Database

  val db: Database = Database.forConfig("db.default")
}
```

DBFactory is again an abstraction:

import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile

```
trait DBFactory {

  val driver: JdbcProfile

  import driver.api._

  val db: Database

}
```

`application.conf`:

```
db.default {
  driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"
  user = "user"
  password = "pass"
  hikaricp {
    minimumIdle = ${db.default.async-executor.minConnections}
    maximumPoolSize = ${db.default.async-executor.maxConnections}
  }
}

jdbc-defaults.slick.profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
lagom.persistence.jdbc.create-tables.auto=false
```

I compile and publish this dependency to nexus and trying to use this in my Lagom Microservice.

Here is the Loader Class:

```
class SlickExapleAppLoader extends LagomApplicationLoader {

  override def load(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication = new SlickExampleApp(context) {
    override def serviceLocator: ServiceLocator = NoServiceLocator
  }

  override def loadDevMode(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication = new SlickExampleApp(context) with LagomDevModeComponents {

  }

  override def describeService = Some(readDescriptor[SlickExampleLMSServiceImpl])
}

abstract class SlickExampleApp(context: LagomApplicationContext)
  extends LagomApplication(context)
    // No Idea which to use and how, nothing clear from doc too.
    //    with ReadSideJdbcPersistenceComponents
    //    with ReadSideSlickPersistenceComponents
    //    with SlickPersistenceComponents
    with AhcWSComponents {


  wire[SlickExampleScheduler]

}
```

I'm trying to implement it in this scheduler:

```
class SlickExampleScheduler @Inject()(lmsService: LMSService,
                                      configuration: Configuration)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
  val brofile = `SomeDomainObject`
  val gson = new Gson()
  val concurrency = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors() * 10

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = 3.minute
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("LMSActorSystem")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  // Getting Exception Initializer here..... For ConfigTable ===> ExceptionLine
  val schedulerImplDao = new SchedulerImplDao(ConfigTable)  

  def hitLMSAPI = {

    println("=============>1")

    schedulerImplDao.doSomething()
  }

  system.scheduler.schedule(2.seconds, 2.seconds) {
    println("=============>")
    hitLMSAPI
  }

}
```

Not sure if it's the correct way, or if it's not what is the correct way of doing this. It is the project requirement to keep the Data Models separate from the service for the obvious reasons of re-usability.

Exception Stack:

```
17:50:38.666 [info] akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://lms-impl-application) [sourceThread=ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1, akkaTimestamp=12:20:38.665UTC, akkaSource=akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://lms-impl-application), sourceActorSystem=lms-impl-application] - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://lms-impl-application@127.0.0.1:45805] - Started up successfully
17:50:38.707 [info] akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://lms-impl-application) [sourceThread=lms-impl-application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6, akkaTimestamp=12:20:38.707UTC, akkaSource=akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://lms-impl-application), sourceActorSystem=lms-impl-application] - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://lms-impl-application@127.0.0.1:45805] - No seed-nodes configured, manual cluster join required
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.slick.init.impl.SlickExampleScheduler.<init>(SlickExampleScheduler.scala:29)
    at com.slick.init.impl.SlickExampleApp.<init>(SlickExapleAppLoader.scala:42)
    at com.slick.init.impl.SlickExapleAppLoader$$anon$2.<init>(SlickExapleAppLoader.scala:17)
    at com.slick.init.impl.SlickExapleAppLoader.loadDevMode(SlickExapleAppLoader.scala:17)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.server.LagomApplicationLoader.load(LagomApplicationLoader.scala:76)
    at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$5(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:176)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$3(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:173)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:163)
    at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$2(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:149)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:251)
    at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$1(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:147)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:658)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.db.models.LoginTable.<init>(LoginTable.scala:29)
    at com.example.db.models.LoginTable$.<init>(LoginTable.scala:293)
    at com.example.db.models.LoginTable$.<clinit>(LoginTable.scala)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it is woking:

```
abstract class SlickExampleApp(context: LagomApplicationContext) extends LagomApplication(context)
  with SlickPersistenceComponents with AhcWSComponents {

  override implicit lazy val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("LMSActorSystem")

  override lazy val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  override lazy val lagomServer = serverFor[SlickExampleLMSService](wire[SlickExampleLMSServiceImpl])
  lazy val externalService = serviceClient.implement[LMSService]

  override def connectionPool: ConnectionPool = new HikariCPConnectionPool(environment)

  override def jsonSerializerRegistry: JsonSerializerRegistry = new JsonSerializerRegistry {
    override def serializers: immutable.Seq[JsonSerializer[_]] = Vector.empty
  }

  val loginTable = wire[LoginTable]

  wire[SlickExampleScheduler]

}
```

**> One thing I'd like to report is**: Lagom [docs](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/scala/PersistentEntityRDBMS.html#Configuration) about the application.conf configuration of slick is not correct, it misleaded me for two days, the I digged into the Liberary code and this is how it goes:

```
private val readSideConfig = system.settings.config.getConfig("lagom.persistence.read-side.jdbc")
  private val jdbcConfig = system.settings.config.getConfig("lagom.persistence.jdbc")
  private val createTables = jdbcConfig.getConfig("create-tables")
  val autoCreateTables: Boolean = createTables.getBoolean("auto")

  // users can disable the usage of jndiDbName for userland read-side operations by
  // setting the jndiDbName to null. In which case we fallback to slick.db.
  // slick.db must be defined otherwise the application will fail to start
  val db = {
    if (readSideConfig.hasPath("slick.jndiDbName")) {
      new InitialContext()
        .lookup(readSideConfig.getString("slick.jndiDbName"))
        .asInstanceOf[Database]
    } else if (readSideConfig.hasPath("slick.db")) {
      Database.forConfig("slick.db", readSideConfig)
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("Cannot start because read-side database configuration is missing. " +
        "You must define either 'lagom.persistence.read-side.jdbc.slick.jndiDbName' or 'lagom.persistence.read-side.jdbc.slick.db' in your application.conf.")
    }
  }

  val profile = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("slick", readSideConfig).profile
```

The configuration it requires is very much different than the suggested one on the [Doc](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/scala/PersistentEntityRDBMS.html#Configuration).